# Неравномерное соединение массивов python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, алгоритм

У меня есть два массива:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

bits = ['bit1', 'bit2', 'bit3', 'bit4', 'bit5', 'bit6']
```

Я хочу, чтобы к каждому элементу bits присваивались значения из a, при этом как можно больше, но чтобы они распределялись равномерно.

Мой код:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

bots = ['bit1', 'bit2', 'bit3', 'bit4', 'bit5', 'bit6']

old_i = 0
for i, bot in enumerate(bots):
    new_i = int(len(a) / len(bots)) * (i + 1)
    print(bot, a[old_i:new_i])
    old_i = new_i
```

Пример:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

bits = ['bit1', 'bit2', 'bit3', 'bit4', 'bit5', 'bit6']
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема: когда количество элементов в а не кратно bits, обрезается часть элементов из а.

Пример:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

bots = ['bit1', 'bit2', 'bit3', 'bit4', 'bit5', 'bit6']
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы в случае нечетности, некоторым значениям из bits присваивалось по 2 элемента, а некоторым по одному. Вот так:

```
bit1 [1, 2]
bit2 [3, 4]
bit3 [5, 6]
bit4 [7, 8]
bit5 [9, 10]
bit6 [11]
```

Comment: "Некоторым" не совсем понятная формулировка. Как должны распределяться элементы списка `a`? Последовательно, в случайном порядке или как-то еще?

Comment: Последовательно. Можете пример кода посмотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
bots = ['bit1', 'bit2', 'bit3', 'bit4', 'bit5', 'bit6']

res = np.array_split(a, divmod(len(a),len(bots))[1]+1)
print(res)
```

результат:

```
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6]), array([7, 8]), array([ 9, 10]), array([11])]
```

Comment: Да, это то что нужно, правда для вывода, который мне нужен я еще добавил:
zip(np.array_split(all_cities, divmod(len(all_cities), len(bots))[1] + 1), bots)